# How do I stop RewriteRule from going into an endless loop?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Lets say I have a file named `FILE%20NAME[1].png` on my server.

The browser requests `FILE%20NAME%5B1%5D.png`, escaping the square brackets, which Apache interprets as `FILE NAME[1].png` and of course cannot find.

I know I should just rename the file, but how would I write a redirect rule for a quick fix in .htaccess?
I tried

```
RewriteRule ^folder/FILE\sNAME\[1\].png /folder/FILE\%20NAME\[1\].png [R=301,QSA,L,NE]
```

which results in an endless loop because the rewritten filename still matches the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `%` (percent) sign - because otherwise `%20` gets interpreted as  (space).

`%` escapes to `%25`,  replacing `%20` for `%2520` should do the trick.

See also: [Percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule ^folder/FILE\sNAME\[1\].png /folder/FILE\%2520NAME\[1\].png [R=301,QSA,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You're mistaken about the problem to begin with -- the problem isn't that the brackets are escaped. The proper request to send to get a file named "FILE%20NAME[1].png" on the filesystem would be "FILE%2520NAME%5B1%5D.png" in the URL.
2. If you just used an `Alias` or a non-redirect `RewriteRule` then there would be no problem with loops.
3. I'm pretty certain that if you take care of what I said in problem 1, then there won't be a problem with loops either, because when you send back the proper redirect target, then the new request URL will contain `%2520` (decoded: `%20`), which won't be matched by `\s`, and so the rule won't apply.

Comment: 1. May be, but the point is the browser sends out the request, so I have no control over it (Firefox anyway)

Comment: @bluegray of course it does, but you're wrong about *what* it's sending and why.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but the generated html src is `FILE%20NAME[1].png` which the browser escapes to `FILE%20NAME%5B1%5D.png` leaving the `%20` as is and escaping the `[]`'s.

Comment: The HTML is incorrect. The correct HTML would be `<img src="FILE%2520NAME%5B1%5D.png">`. You can get away with leaving the `[` and `]` unescaped due to browser laxness, but leaving the `%` unescaped causes the exact problem you're having. If the HTML wasn't incorrect to begin with then you wouldn't need anything on the server side.